# ¿Busco al señor Gómez , o Busco a señor Gómez?

Tags: gramática

Why is this correct

> Busco al señor Gómez.

but not this?

> Busco a señor Gómez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta reemplazarlo por un pronombre. Si resulta ser de tercera persona, entonces se lo puede pensar meramente como sustantivo y por lo tanto se usa el artículo—'el señor', 'la señora', etc. Es lo que ocurre en tu caso:

> Busco al señor Gómez. ('*Busco a **el** señor Gómez', lo busco a **él**)

Cuando el pronombre es de segunda persona—o más precisamente *usted*, ya que la palabra es usada en registro formal—'señor' se convierte en un vocativo y por lo tanto no se usa artículo.

> ¡Señor Gómez, lo estaba buscando! (A **usted** lo estaba buscando)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Realmente disfruto las respuestas que recibo aquí!